# How to implement video streaming in html without plugins like flash/silverlight?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, video, video-streaming

I have a video which is in wmv format. And i want to have this in my ASP.NET MVC application and support streaming so that users can stream and start viewing the video. Also i do not want to rely on third part controls like flash/silverlight/quickplayer etc. How can i achieve?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425218/html5-video-tag-in-chrome-wmv Note that WMV is a windows specific format and may not work as expected on non-windows systems.

Comment: I am not looking for HTML5 based solution as still some browser are far away from it....otherwise i would have referred that question...

Comment: If you are not comfortable using HTML5 you will need to depend on flash/silverlight/whatsoever I think.

Answer (score 1):

html5 supports this video streaming. Please check http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp It doesn't rely on any third party plugins, if the browser can support html5 then it is simple. Most famous browsers supports more or less html5 features.
Thanks