# <video> tag does not work in Chrome when source is a http stream

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, vlc, http-streaming

Currently I have VLC media player streaming a video file out through http on port 8082. I have a webserver running a page with the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay="true" controls="controls">
        <source src="http://localhost:8082/stream.ogg">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works with Firefox. I can see the stream that VLC is sending out playing in the browser with a 5 second delay. However, this code does not work in Chrome. I have also tried a mp4 stream and that does not work either.

I am wondering what the issue is here. Chrome support is vital for us. Does chrome not support http streams for `<video>`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425218/html5-video-tag-in-chrome-wmv

Comment: are you running it locally and if so try removing the 'http://localhost:8082/' also it might be to do with your codec .ogg try a .gov also .webm versions and adding the type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>

Comment: I am running it locally, but its another server running on a different port. localhost:8082 is the vlc streaming server. I tried adding the type attribute, but it doesn't help.